# Dynamic creating tooltip using JQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html-parsing

I searched for some nice easy to use jQuery tooltip plugin but couldn't found any useful.

My requirements are that I am creating a list which I retreived asych from server through javascript and append in the page, and I want to use tooltip on this list. I am going to show JSON code in tooltip.

So I need a plugin which can allow html as tooltip and it can be created dynamically.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [jQuery Tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) from flowplayer.org. The tooltip itself is just a div and content of that div could be anything.

Comment: I checked this plugin before but didn't try it may be i am lazy :(  I tried again and did some testing and its working just have to work on some positioning problem. Thanks :)

Comment: ok its not working the way i think. I tried to create tooltip for dynamic elements i am creating in a loop but its creating tooltip for last element only.

Comment: You have dynamic links or dynamic content for static links? Two different things. In any case, show the relevant code.